# Why does TypeScript return incorrect types for my higher-order function?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have different types returned based on a the result of a high order `useTestSubColRef` function.

Why am I getting the wrong TypeScript types?

```TypeScript
const subColRefWithId = <T extends DocumentData>(
  collectionName: string,
  docId: string,
  subCollectionName: string,
): CollectionReference<WithId<T>> => {
  return col<WithId<T>>(collectionName, docId, subCollectionName);
};

const subColRef = <T extends DocumentData>(
  collectionName: string,
  docId: string,
  subCollectionName: string,
): CollectionReference<T> => {
  return col<T>(collectionName, docId, subCollectionName);
};

export const useTestSubColRef = (docId: string, withId: boolean = true) => {
  return withId
    ? subColRefWithId<SerpLocalPackItem>("colName", docId, "subColName")
    : subColRef<SerpLocalPackItem>("colName", docId, "subColName");
};

// test1 should be CollectionReference<WithId<SerpLocalPackItem>>, but it is showing as CollectionReference<SerpLocalPackItem> (missing WithId)
const test1 = useTestSubColRef("docId");

// test2 should be CollectionReference<WithId<SerpLocalPackItem>>, but it is showing as CollectionReference<SerpLocalPackItem> (missing WithId)
const test2 = useTestSubColRef("docId", true);

// test2 should be CollectionReference<SerpLocalPackItem> and is corrrect
const test2 = useTestSubColRef("docId", false);
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mre], including all necessary types (but again, as minimal as possible). It's hard to help you when the question uses types that aren't included.

Comment: If you want the return type to depend on the argument, write [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) or a conditional type.